# Not receiving any emails from my salesforce profile for my workflow!

Tags: email, workflow

I have setup a workflow for an email update for whenever a new lead is created. But for some reason I am not receiving any emails from my Salesforce account. I even assured it by the sending the test emails, which I do receive it. I can't figure out what's wrong! Please help me out.[image: Workflow Rule]
[image: Workflow Action]

Comment: What's your current `Email Deliverability` setting?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Access Level: All emails, Bounce management: Activated, Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms: 'Checked',
Enable Sender ID compliance: 'Checked',  Notify sender when mass email completes: 'Checked', TLS Setting: Preferred.

Comment: is the workflow activated?  did you check email logs to see what errors SFDC detected when it sent an outbound email?